# How to display the name of the latest commit on GitHub to my website?

Tags: javascript, html, github, github-api

I need to simply get the name of the latest commit from GitHub and display it *preferably* in a static way on the web.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "in a static way"?

Comment: To get the latest commit from a Github project, you can probably use something from there: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-commits

Comment: @MauriceNino In a jam-stack/static website without a direct backend, something that would be hosted in GitHub pages for example.

Comment: Ah okay - should be no problem if Github allows CORS, which it probably does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @MauriceNino commented, you can use `https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/{repo}/commits?per_page=1` to just get the latest commit.

The example below fetches from https://github.com/ChocolateLoverRaj/canvideo and puts the result in a `<pre>`. [Link to api request](https://api.github.com/repos/ChocolateLoverRaj/canvideo/commits?per_page=1).

```js
fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/ChocolateLoverRaj/canvideo/commits?per_page=1')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = res[0].commit.message
  })
```

```html
<pre id="message">Loading</pre>
```